# VSTS Branching Statery & CICD pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, devops, continuous-deployment

I have referred the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/concepts/git-branching-guidance?view=vsts for knowing more about Branching concept. And if my understanding is correct, there should be a master branch, then a release branch then a support branch and a feature branch in common.

And the merging between the branches should be defined as below:

1. Create the master branch(with code added to it).
2. A release branch is then created from the master branch(else know as a topic branch).
3. Then create a support branch to fix bugs from the release branch and then merge them back into the release branch in a pull request.
4. Create a new feature branch off the master branch to port the changes. Cherry-pick the changes from the release branch to your new feature branch. And then merge the feature branch back into the master branch in a second pull request.

Coming to the question, assume that i have 4 environments, such as - Development, Test, Pre-Production & Production. Here i need to have a branching and merging mechanism and needs to setup cicd pipeline in VSTS.

1. How will i define the CICD pipeline for the above above case, if i use MS recommended branching and merging mechanism? Whether all the deployments will be done from the master branch only? (That's from Master branch, build & deploy to-> Dev -> Test -> Pre prod -> Prod environment?). Do i need to note of any other things in this?.
   [image]
2. Or do i need to have a separate branching and merging mechanism, such that i need to have separate branches for each of the four environments and should define separate pipelines like the below screen?
   [image]

Comment: It depend on what's the code do you want to set CI/CD for the environments (Development, Test, Pre-Production & Production). Does the four environments deploy with the same code on the same branch or different?

Comment: i was looking for some standard approach. Since when i search for branching concepts and pipeline, i am getting different approaches and partial implementation references, and got confused which is the right one and how the whole process should run, starting from code check-in to deployment, for 4 environments.

Comment: For the standard branching model, you can refer https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/. It's a wide used branching structure which is also applied for gitflow. And based on the branching model, you can CI/CD to dev environment (by develop branch) and production environment (by master branch). If you design to deploy four environments separately, you can adjust the branching model correspondingly.

Comment: Another doubt, i came across is that, did CI/CD ever meant that there should be a single release pipeline than runs from the main branch -> Dev->Test->Pre-Prod->Prod. Or the individual pipelines between each of the environments and separate releases  to these environments are also acceptable?.

Comment: Each environment is for a single branch only. Such as for Dev environment, the CI/CD aims to check the code from develop branch. Only when the code from develop branch has been qualified, you can merge it into master or create a release branch to prepare the next release for production.

Comment: Thanks for the info, please add it in the answer section, let me mark it as closed.

Comment: I added it just now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the standard branching model, you can refer [A successful Git branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). It's a wide used branching structure which is also applied for gitflow. And based on the branching model, you can CI/CD to dev environment (by `develop` branch) and production environment (by `master` branch). If you design to deploy four environments separately, you can adjust the branching model correspondingly.

And each environment is for a single branch only. Such as for Dev environment, the CI/CD aims to check the code from `develop` branch. Only when the code from `develop` branch has been qualified, you can merge it into `master` or create a release branch to prepare the next release for production.